# rand() not giving values within numbers specified (in C)

Tags: c, random

I just want it to give me values between 1 and 6, but it's giving me this instead:

```
P1d1 = 1445768086

P1d2 = -2

P2d1 = 1982468450

P2d2 = 198281572
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (){

srand(time(NULL));

/*Player 1*/

int P1d1 = 1 + rand() % 6;  //Rolls Player 1's first die; random # between 1-6
int P1d2 = 1+ rand() % 6;  //Rolls Player 1's second die; random # between 1-6
int P1total = P1d1 + P1d2;  //Takes total of both rolls

/*Player 2*/

int P2d1 = 1 + rand() % 6; //Rolls Player 2's first die; random # between 1-6
int P2d2 = 1 + rand() % 6; //Rolls Player 2's second die; random # between 1-6
int P2total = P2d1 + P2d2; //Takes total of both rolls

printf("P1d1 = %d\nP1d2 = %d\nP2d1 = %d\n P2d2 = %d\n");

}
```

I'm not allowed to use functions as we have not covered them in class yet. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Is __that__ your actual `printf()` line? You forgot your variables.

Comment: As the code is now, nothing should be printed as output. `printf` is not given any variables to print

Comment: @Pankrates It's undefined behavior, so anything may happen, printing nothing is one possible result.

Comment: @Downvoters care to comment what was wrong with the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `printf` has no variables specified. You are therefore getting random garbage printed, not the actual variable values you're looking for.

You should have this:

```
printf("P1d1 = %d\nP1d2 = %d\nP2d1 = %d\n P2d2 = %d\n", P1d1, P1d2, P2d1, P2d2);
```